# File uploading errors in CI

Tags: image, codeigniter, file-upload

I am using multiple file upload module in CodeIgniter; the script is totally successful, just a simple error, might be a silly one is happening.

First I would like to share a concept. In a website people are registering using their email id now when people are registering using a email id, a folder for that guy gets created in the server by the name of the email id. Say I register in the site by email id `saswat.saz.routroy@gmail.com`, then when i log in the session starts as `$_SESSION['logged_user']="saswat.saz.routroy@gmail.com"`.

Again when I am registering, a folder gets created in the server with the name `saswat.saz.routroy@gmail.com`. Now I want to upload images into the folder "saswat.saz.routroy@gmail.com".

I am using the script

```
foreach($_FILES['photo']['name'] as $key=>$val)
          {
             if($_FILES['photo']['name'][$key]=="")
                {
                  //return "Successfully Added";
                }
             else if($_FILES['photo']['name'][$key]!='' && ($_FILES['photo']['type'][$key]='jpeg'
                     || $_FILES['photo']['type'][$key]='jpg' || $_FILES['photo']['type'][$key]='JPG'
                     || $_FILES['photo']['type'][$key]='JPEG') )
                {

                      $f_name=$_FILES['photo']['name'][$key];
                      $s_name=array();
                      $s_name=explode('.',$f_name);
                      $name=$s_name[0];
                      $name="(".$order_date.")".$name;
                      $slug= $name;
                      $slug = trim($slug," ");
                      $slug = trim($slug,"-");
                      $slug=str_replace(" ", "-", $slug);
                      $slug=str_replace("/", "-", $slug);
                      $slug=str_replace("|", "-", $slug);
                      $slug=str_replace("!", "-", $slug);
                      $slug=str_replace("+", "-", $slug);
                      $slug=str_replace("*", "-", $slug);

                      $data = array(
                             'photo_id' => NULL,
                             'order_id' => $last_order_id,
                             'user_id' => $user_id,
                             'photo_name'=>$name,
                             'photo_folder'=>$_SESSION['logged_user'],
                             'order_date'=>$order_date
                             );
                      if($this->db->insert('photo_table', $data))
                        {
                             $last_id=mysql_insert_id();
                             $slug= $last_id."-".$slug;
                             $this->db->query("UPDATE photo_table
                             SET photo_slug='$slug' WHERE photo_id='$last_id'");
                        }
                      $image= $_SESSION['logged_user'].'/'.md5(uniqid(rand())).$_FILES['photo']['name'][$key];
                      $img="./".$image;
                      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key],$img);
                      $fullpath=$image;
                      $this->db->query("UPDATE photo_table
                                SET photo_path='$fullpath' WHERE photo_id='$last_id'");

                }

          }
          return "Successfully Uploaded";
```

Where `$_SESSION['logged_user']="saswat.saz.routroy@gmail.com"`. Now, this script is not giving any error, but still files arent getting uploaded, although the database is getting updated as it should be.

But if I use the script:

```
$image= 'photo_folder/'.md5(uniqid(rand())).$_FILES['photo']['name'][$key];
```

instead of

```
$image= $_SESSION['logged_user'].'/'.md5(uniqid(rand())).$_FILES['photo']['name'][$key];
```

then files are getting uploaded perfectly. That means its just about the folder name that's causing error, but I need to upload file in such method.

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload as

```
foreach($_FILES['photo']['name'] as $key=>$val){ }
```

you should use

```
print_r($_FILES['photo']['name']);
die();
```

To understand the array found.
Its not the way you thinking, in this case it returns a 2D array in 0th index name and in 1st index an array which contains further index no. and name of the image.
You should split this array into a victuals arrays to pass in the function

```
do_upload();
```

this way

```
<?php
class Uploads extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function do_upload($field="1")
{
    $error_data=array();
    $success_data=array();
    $data = array();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    if($this->input->post("btn"))
    {   
        $images = array();
        $name=array();
        $field=0;
        $config['upload_path'] = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../assets/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        foreach ($_FILES["fileimage"]['name'] as $k=>$v)
        {
            $_FILES['images[]']['name']= $_FILES['fileimage']['name'][$k];
            $_FILES['images[]']['type']= $_FILES['fileimage']['type'][$k];
            $_FILES['images[]']['tmp_name']= $_FILES['fileimage']['tmp_name'][$k];
            $_FILES['images[]']['error']= $_FILES['fileimage']['error'][$k];
            $_FILES['images[]']['size']= $_FILES['fileimage']['size'][$k];

            $field++;
            $name[]=$_FILES['fileimage']['name'][$k];

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("images[]"))
            {

                $error_data[] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $success_data[]="";
            }
            else
            {
                $success_data[] = $this->upload->data();
                $error_data[]="";
            }
        }
        $data['name']=$name;
        $data['error']=$error_data;
        $data['success']=$success_data;

    }
    $data['field']=$field;
    $this->load->view('upload_form',$data);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be the folder name.

Can you use user ID for the folder name instead?

E.g.

```
$image= $_SESSION['user_id'].'/'.md5(uniqid(rand())).$_FILES['photo']['name'][$key];
```

Otherwise you will need to remove all the characters from their email that are not allowed in folder names (which is dependent on the OS).